# How to replace certain values pulled from MySQL DB while printing to excel spreadsheet in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I'm using PHP to create an excel document with the data I'm pulling from a MySQL Database.

While cycling through the rows at the end and printing out my data to each cell, I want to replace each cell that has the string/int equivical of *'-1'* to *'0'*.

Here's my code so far,

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=exported-data.csv');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM db_table";
$sth = $db->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();

$filename = date('d.m.Y').'.csv';
$data = fopen($filename, 'w');

while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $csv = implode(',', $row) . "\n";
    fwrite($data, $csv);
    print_r($csv);

}

echo "\r\n";
```

This works efficiently with getting the data from the db and outputting to an excel spreadsheet but how would I check each record pulled and replace it with a 0 if the record is -1?

So visually, if my database looked like this:

```
id    mon    tues   wed
85    -1     -1     75
36    -1     12     -1
```

The excel spreadsheet would pop out like so:

```
85    0     0     75
36    0     12    0
```

Comment: So `print_r($row)` and check what field you need?

Comment: @u_mulder I want to check before printing to the excel spreadsheet, and replace if equals.

Comment: `if ($row[name] == '-1')`?

Comment: @u_mulder there's multiple columns, I'm about to edit the question.

Comment: If you do it with PHP it's going to be "Row By Agonizing Row", however, it would be more efficient to do it at the SQL level using [CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) within your select statement. I can elaborate further if you can't get it figured out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with u_mulder about replacing the -1 results with 0. I would build upon that with some error checking, cache busting, and I would use PHP's fputcsv function to stream the file directly to STDOUT. This will reduce memory usage, increase performance, and ensure that field values containing double quotes or commas are correctly parsed.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=exported-data.csv');
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM db_table";
$sth = $db->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();

$file = fopen('php://output', 'w');
if(false === $file) {
    throw new Exception("Failed to create output stream resource.");
}

while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    foreach($row as &$field) {
        if("-1" == strval($field)) {
            $field = "0";
        }
    }

    if(false === fputcsv($file, $row)) {
        throw new Exception("Failed to write row to CSV file.");
    }
}

fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to do this:

```
while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    // check every key of $row
    // use & to pass $value by reference
    foreach ($row as &$value) {
        // use strval to get string representation of a $value
        if (strval($value) == '-1') {
            $value = '0';
        }
    }

    $csv = implode(',', $row) . "\n";
    fwrite($data, $csv);
    print_r($csv);
}
```

Comment: This is inefficient and should be done at the SQL level.

Comment: @amatuerEverything can you give me an example of something more efficient? maybe post as answer?

Comment: @VolcovMeter - I have added my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this at the SQL level will be much faster then analyzing each row individually with PHP especially as your database gets larger. Use [CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html).

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=exported-data.csv');

$sql = "
    SELECT
        id
        ,CASE WHEN monday = -1 THEN 0 ELSE monday END AS monday
        ,CASE WHEN tuesday = -1 THEN 0 ELSE tuesday END AS tuesday 
        ,CASE WHEN wednesday = -1 THEN 0 ELSE wednesday END AS wednesday
    FROM db_table";
$sth = $db->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();

$filename = date('d.m.Y').'.csv';
$data = fopen($filename, 'w');

while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $csv = implode(',', $row) . "\n";
    fwrite($data, $csv);
    print_r($csv);

}

echo "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter `$row` to replace negative values by `0`:

```
$row = array_map(function ($val) { return $val > 0 ? $val : 0; }, $row);
```

Also, consider using `fputcsv()` to generate valid CSV files instead of trying to do it yourself. Simply separating values by `,` may work when you are dealing only with numbers but this may create problems with strings.

```
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $row = array_map(function ($val) { return $val > 0 ? $val : 0; }, $row);
    fputcsv($data, $row);
    fputcsv($output, $row);
}
```

Another problem that you may face when generating CSV files to be opened with Excel is localization. Excel expects the CSV files it opens to be formatted according to the local system localization settings. A record such as `1,2,3,1.23` may work in English, having each number separated in a column and having `1.23` with its decimals interpreted correctly, but will not work on many others languages, specially when `,` is used as decimal separator instead of `.`.

With that in mind you may want to implement localization to your CSV aswell, and your best guess is to use the client's browser language settings:

```
$locale = isset($_COOKIE['locale']) ? $_COOKIE['locale'] : $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];
$locale = preg_split('/[,;]/', $locale);
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale[0]);
$locale = localeconv();

$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $row = array_map(function ($val) { return $val > 0 ? $val : 0; }, $row);
    fputcsv($data, $row, $locale['decimal_point'] == ',' ? ';' : ',');
    fputcsv($output, $row, $locale['decimal_point'] == ',' ? ';' : ',');
}
```

Now, if you don't want to have this complication, you can instead generate real Excel .XLSX files using a library such as PHPExcel.